# Linear map from quotient space to another space is well-defined

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T : V \to W$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and is invariant under $T$. Then the map $T' : V/U \to W$ defined by $T'(v + U) = Tv$ is a linear map. I am struggling to show that this map is well-defined. If $U = \ker(T)$, then it would be easy to show. However, since $U$ is just any invariant subspace, I'm not sure how to proceed.

I started by saying suppose $v_1 + U = v_2 + U \implies v_1 - v_2 \in U$. Since $U$ is only invariant, and we made no assumption on its relation to the kernel of $T$, I can't say $T(v_1 - v_2) = 0 \implies Tv_1 = Tv_2$.

Comment: "$U$ is invariant under $T$" makes no sense when $W\neq V$. "$T$-invariant" means $T(U)\leq U$, so it usually only applies to operators. What are you really doing?

Comment: This doesn't work in general. Take $T\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $T(x,y)=(0,y)$. Then $U=\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y\in \mathbb{R}\} = R(T)$ is $T$-invariant. If we tried to define $T\colon \mathbb{R}^2/U\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $T(v+U) = T(v)$, this is not well defined: $(2,3)+U = (2,4)+U$ since $(2,4)-(2,3)=(0,1)\in U$, but $T(2,3)=(0,3)$ and $T(2,4) = (0,4)\neq T(2,3)$.

Comment: Indeed, the statement is just false. What you need is to assume that $U\subseteq Ker(T)$.

Comment: In general, the map $T\colon V/U\to W$ given by $T(v+U)=T(v)$ is well-defined if and only if $U\leq \ker(T)$. Indeed, we know that if $U\leq \ker(T)$ then this is well defined. If $U$ is not contained in $\ker(T)$, then let $u\in U$ with $u\notin \ker(T)$. Then $0+U=u+U$, but $T(0)\neq T(u)$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arturo noted the question is ill formed if $V \neq W$ (or at least $U \subseteq W$). Invariance means $T(U) \subseteq U$ and since $T(U) \subseteq W$ the image must be of the same space.

But even if we were to assume $V = W$, this statement still wouldn't be true.

Consider $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\pmatrix{5& 0\\ 0& 5}$, very simple. Now of course the $x$-axis is an invariant subspace, call it $U$.

But notice $(1, 7) + U = (2, 7) + U$ but obviously $T(2, 7) = (10, 35) \neq (5, 35) = T(1, 7)$.

So TL;DR: the question is ill formed as given and even if well formed- still false.

It would actually be a nice exercise to determine what kind of space $U$ must be in order to ensure well formedness. Hint, it should involve the kernel in some way after all.